# Chrome extension: force event page to stay open?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using `chrome.tabCapture.capture` in order to capture a tab's audio from my background page:

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture({
           audio: true,
           video: false
       }, (stream) => {
           if (null == stream) {
               chrome.extension.sendMessage({
                   type: "powerOff"
               });
           } else {
               methods.createAudio(stream);
           })
```

The tab is captured and uncaptured by sending requests from the popup.

I would like the extension to not run in the background while the tab is uncaptured, but when I switch the background persistence to 'false' in the manifest, the event page stops working (capturing) when I switch focus from the captured window.

The event page [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) says :
"If you're using message passing, be sure to close unused message ports. The event page will not shut down until all message ports are closed."

So I'm thinking about using:

```
setInterval(function () {
        console.log("Tab Captured. Forcing event page to stay open..");
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage("CAPTURING");
    }, 1000);
```

This in order to force the page to stay open by sending a message to the popup every second.

Is this method safe, and what's the recommended interval value?

```
Manifest:  
{
"background": {
   "scripts": ["js/bg/bg.html" ],
   "persistent": false
},
 "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "style/128_off.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_title": "__MSG_mainTitle__"
},
"default_locale": "en",
"description": "__MSG_description__",
"icons": {
  "128": "style/128_on.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "__MSG_name__",
"offline_enabled": true,
"options_page": "options.html",
"permissions": [ "*://*/*", "tabCapture", "tabs", "storage" ],
"version": "2.3.9"
}
```

Comment: Yes, 1000 is okay and safe. The alternative is to just open a single persistent port connection.